# CodeIgniter with Jqgrid

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, jqgrid

I've been working on jqGrid for the last 3 days.

I've been able to populate the grid, but now  I can't get to work the buttons/features of the jqGrid like add, edit, save or even delete a row.

Any suggestion/opinions on how to do this will be really helpful.

btw- I'm using codeigniter with jqGrid

this is my js file

```
$("#listFlex").jqGrid({
    url: root + mod + '/listview2',
    datatype: "json",
    colNames:['','role_code','role_description'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'role_id',index:'role_id', width:50, align:"center",hidden:true},
        {name:'role_code',index:'role_code', width:80},
        {name:'role_desc',index:'role_desc', width:100,align:"left"}
    ],
    buttons : [
        {name: $.i18n._(action_lang,'delete'), bclass: 'delete', onpress: df_delete_1},
        {separator: true}
    ],
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    pager: '#pager2',
    sortname: 'role_id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    onSelectRow: function(id){
        if(id && id!==lastsel){
            jQuery('#listFlex').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel);
            jQuery('#listFlex').jqGrid('editRow',id,true);
            lastsel=id;
        }
    },
    autowidth: true,
    height: "200",
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption:"JSON Example",
    editurl:"sec_role/post"
});

jQuery("#listFlex").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager2',{edit:true,add:true,del:true});

//edit data
$("#bedata").click(function(){
    var gr = jQuery("#listFlex").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
    if( gr != null )
        jQuery("#listFlex").jqGrid('editGridRow',gr,{height:280,reloadAfterSubmit:false});
    else
        alert("Please Select Row");
});

$("#dedata").click(function(){
    var gr = jQuery("#listFlex").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
    if( gr != null )
        jQuery("#listFlex").jqGrid('delGridRow',gr,{reloadAfterSubmit:false});
    else
        alert("Please Select Row to delete!");
});
```

view file

```
<table id="listFlex" class="listFlex" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
<div id="pager2" class="scroll" style="text-align: center;"></div>
<input type="BUTTON" id="bedata" value="Edit Selected" /> <!--edit-->
<input type="BUTTON" id="dedata" value="Delete Selected" /><!-- add-->
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the logs? Have you stepped through the code with FireBug to see what is actually happening and if any JS errors are being thrown?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is that you are not including jqModal.js and jqDnR.js. They are located in src

Comment: hi, got it working. i really didnt include it in the loader.js. :D. but my problem now is its not deleting the rows in my db. but in my window its able to edit & delete but when i refresh the page its not. This is the error in my firebug. <p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined variable: json</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/sec_role.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 129</p>

hope you can help me with this one too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#bedata").click(function(){
    var gr = ***jQuery("#listFlex").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');***
    if( gr != null )
        jQuery("#listFlex").jqGrid('editGridRow',gr,{height:280,reloadAfterSubmit:false});
    else
        alert("Please Select Row");
});
```

test this

```
jQuery("#bedata").click(function()
 { var gr = ***jQuery("#listFlex").getGridParam('selrow');***
 if( gr != null ) jQuery("#listFlex").editGridRow(gr,{height:280,reloadAfterSubmit:false});
  else alert("Please Select Row");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this library+helper to implement jqgrid with codeigniter
http://blog.markmirandilla.com/2011/09/04/codeigniter-jqgrid-library/